# Swift Timer Check TouchesEnded

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit

Sorry to be awkward but please can I have the full code on how to do this:

I would like a delay of 1 second after every bullet is shot in my game to prevent bullet spam. If possible without creating a separate function for the bullet spawning as I have done this in touchesEnded. So tap, shoot, wait. tap, shoot, wait.  And in the wait, if screen is tapped, nothing happens. Thanks and sorry I am a beginner

```
guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

    //Set up initial location of bullet and properties
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    bullet.name = "Bullet"
    bullet.position = player.position
    bullet.setScale(0.75)
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bullet.size.width/2)
    bullet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
    bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
    bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    bullet.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true



    //Determine offset of location to bullet
    let offset = touchLocation - bullet.position

    //Stops Bullet from shooting backwards
    if (offset.y < 0) { return }

    addChild(bullet)

    //Get the direction of where to shoot
    let direction = offset.normalized()

    //Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
    let shootAmount = direction * 1000

    //Add the shoot amount to the current position
    let realDest = shootAmount + bullet.position

    //Create the actions

    if currentGameState == gameState.inGame {
    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: 1.2)
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    bullet.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fired = false

// Other code...

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

    if fired == false {

        fired = true

        //Set up initial location of bullet and properties
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.name = "Bullet"
        bullet.position = player.position
        bullet.setScale(0.75)
        bullet.zPosition = 1
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bullet.size.width/2)
        bullet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        bullet.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true



        //Determine offset of location to bullet
        let offset = touchLocation - bullet.position

        //Stops Bullet from shooting backwards
        if (offset.y < 0) { return }

        addChild(bullet)

        //Get the direction of where to shoot
        let direction = offset.normalized()

        //Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
        let shootAmount = direction * 1000

        //Add the shoot amount to the current position
        let realDest = shootAmount + bullet.position

        //Create the actions

        if currentGameState == gameState.inGame {
            let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: 1.2)
            let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            bullet.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))

        }

        run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1), completion: { fired = false })

    }
}
```

This means that every time that a bullet is fired, a timer for 1 second occurs which prevents the bullet code from being run until the time is over. At this point, the Boolean switches back to false allowing the code to be run again.